# Eigen C++; Euclidean Transformation with Eigen::Transform

Tags: c++, geometry, linear-algebra, eigen, eigen3

Given an Euclidean Transformation by a rotation matrix *3x3* `R` and a 3-dimensional translation vector `t`, how can the Euclidean transformation
be implemented using `Eigen::Transform`?

```
X = R * X + t
```

My current approach fails to work:

```
Eigen::Transform<Type, 3, Eigen::Projective>  transformation;
...

Eigen::AngleAxis           rotation(R);
Eigen::Translation<Type,3> translation(t);

transformation = translation * rotation;
```

Now, I want to apply it column-wise on a larger set of vectors, i.e. 
a *3xN* matrix `X` where each column represents a vector to be 
transformed, i.e.

```
 X = transformation * X
```

But, this does not work and produces an assertion:

```
test-depth.exe: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:133: Eigen::Product<Lhs, Rhs, Option>::Product(const Lhs&, const Rhs&) [with _Lhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>; _Rhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; int Option = 0; Eigen::Product<Lhs, Rhs, Option>::Lhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>; Eigen::Product<Lhs, Rhs, Option>::Rhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]: Assertion `lhs.cols() == rhs.rows() && "invalid matrix product" && "if you wanted a coeff-wise or a dot product use the respective explicit functions"' failed.
```

Comment: X should be 4*1 vector from the same type

Comment: You mean, that internally, it generates a 4x3 matrix to combine the rotation and translation. But does this really force me to generate a forth-dimension element? Is there an elegant way around that?

Comment: Read about homogeneous coordinates. BTW, do you really need `Projective`rather than `Affine`?

Answer (score 2):

MBo's comment is right, you used a `Projective` transform that involves full homogeneous coordinates to work with. You need to use an `Affine` transform or `AffineCompact` if you want a `3x4` matrix under the hood.

Comment: I would expect, that there was a way around having a fourth dimension in the vector to be transformed. It is always '1'. I thought, that it could be added internally, efficiently.

Comment: In 3D, a projective transformation is represented by an arbitrary 4x4 matrix, so the 4th component of the output cannot be guessed, and we don't want to silently perform the perspective division, which could also be a division by zero.